# I am getting an error, in soundAdapter class, i dont know how to solve it

Tags: java, android

I got this error and i dont know how to solve it. I making an app with a list of, like tiktok. I divided the design of it into two layouts. I am a beginner and i really dont know where to look and how to solve it, i hope those who know it better will explain to me the error and the solution.

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
        at com.anisacoding.expriment.Adapter.SoundAdapter.getItemCount(SoundAdapter.java:55)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:4044)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3849)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22419)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6584)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1762)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22419)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6584)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22419)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6584)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22419)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6584)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22419)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6584)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22419)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6584)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:1041)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22419)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6584)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3378)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2842)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1888)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8511)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

This is the class that got the error.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;


import com.anisacoding.expriment.Model.SoundModel;
import com.anisacoding.expriment.R;
import com.anisacoding.expriment.VideoEditorFolder.PortraitCameraActivity;

import java.util.List;

public class SoundAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SoundAdapter.SoundViewHolder> {
List<SoundModel> soundModelList;
Context context;

public SoundAdapter(List<SoundModel>soundModelList, Context context){
    this.soundModelList = soundModelList;
    this.context = context;
}
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SoundAdapter.SoundViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
       View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_sound, viewGroup, false);
       return new SoundViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SoundAdapter.SoundViewHolder holder, int position) {

    SoundModel soundModel = soundModelList.get(position);

          holder.sound_title.setText(soundModel.getSound_title());
          holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View view) {
                  Intent intent = new Intent(context, PortraitCameraActivity.class);
                  intent.putExtra("sound_url", soundModel.getSound_file());
                  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                  context.startActivity(intent);
              }
          });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return soundModelList.size();
    }

    public static class SoundViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView sound_title;
        public SoundViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            sound_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        }
    }



    }
```

This are the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView20"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="147dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/library_music"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_library_music" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:maxLength="50"
        android:text="Alaf file song ......."
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView20"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView20"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView20"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline24"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="1.0" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline25"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="1.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Another one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tool="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tool:context=".Activities.SoundActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cross"
        android:layout_width="43dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/cross"
        android:onClick="backBtn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_cross" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Your `soundModelList` is `null`. How do you instantiate your adapter? What value do you pass in?

Answer (score 0):

I think you list giving null object reference. make sure that list is initialize before you send data from activity or fragment to the adapter constructor.

public SoundAdapter(List(space)soundModelList, Context context) space also